# Navigation present to another navigation, how to get back to the root navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My root navigation has a StoreDetailsController，and I am in the StoreDetailsController present to the ShoppingBagNavigationController.They can be infinite present. What should I do when I want to go back to the root navigation?

```
- (void)goBagVC{
  UINavigationController *shoppingBag = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ShoppingBag" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShoppingBagNavigationController"];
ShoppingBagViewController *myshopVC = shoppingBag.viewControllers[0];
[myshopVC passDetailProduct:self.productDetailModel.productID];
[self presentViewController:shoppingBag animated:YES completion:nil];}    

- (void)goRootVC{
[self.navigationController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

I want to go root Controller in goRootVC function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As `ShoppingBagViewController` would be your topmost view after you present it, adding a call `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` to a button press in `ShoppingBagViewController` would dismiss that screen.

The `StoreDetailsController` should be visible once the other screen has been dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're confusing modal presentation and pushing onto a navigation stack. Your goBagVC method is modally presenting a navigation controller on top of the current view controller. If you want to push view controllers onto a navigation stack then you need to start with a navigation controller and call `pushViewController:animated:`

Answer (score 0):

You have to search that view controller in yout navigation controller and then pop to that controller.

**Swift**

```
let vc = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.filter { $0 is StoreDetailsController }.first!
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
```